# todoist - Fetching the list of projects with python library

Tags: python, todoist

I am specifically trying to get the project id given the project name. I saw in the api the api.sync() is supposed to return to me all the projects as in array in a key which I was then planning to iterate through.

I tried using sync with the python library but my projects array is empty, is it some sort of promise mechanism if so how do I wait for success response in python language?

```
import todoist
api = todoist.TodoistAPI(token)
response = api.sync()
projects = response['projects']
for project in projects:
   print(project['name'] + '-' + project['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The python library automatically syncs so the sync method response rarely contains anything useful BUT that information is contained in the api class which has an overridden _find_object method. Therefore you can use the same notation as a dict to find elements - i.e. **api['projects']**.

I know this is an old question but I'd been having this problem and was struggling to find an answer so hopefully this will be useful to someone at some point!

Answer (score 0):

The library takes care of the Sync for you. In case you already did a Sync in the past, it stores a hash into your `$HOME/.todoist-sync/`. I recommend you to try to clean this path and try again.